# Bootstrap Tabs - Next and previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with my Bootstrap Tabs.

I defined a `scrollTop` function on next button. The scrolling is working fine but the tab is jumping from 1 to 3.

**My JS code:**

```
<script>

$('.btnNext').click(function(){

     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(".expect").offset().top
    }, 800,

    function () {
          $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    }
);

});

  $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

</script>
```

**HTML Code** :

```
<div class="step-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item active" style="padding:3px;">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab">STAP 01</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" style="padding:3px;">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab">STAP 02</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" style="padding:3px;">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" role="tab">STAP 03</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" style="padding:3px;">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab5" role="tab">STAP 03</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" style="padding:3px;">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab5" role="tab">STAP 03</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" style="padding:3px;">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab6" role="tab">STAP 03</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="step-panes">
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
            <p>CONTENT TABS 01<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>XXXXXX<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>XXXXXXX<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p><a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2" role="tabpanel">
            <p>CONTENT TABS 01<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>XXXXXX<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p><a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a> <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3" role="tabpanel">
            <p>CONTENT TABS 03</p><a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a> <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4" role="tabpanel">
            <p>CONTENT TABS 03</p><a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a> <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5" role="tabpanel">
            <p>CONTENT TABS 03</p><a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a> <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6" role="tabpanel">
            <p>CONTENT TABS 03</p><a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a> <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Live: http://www.bootply.com/StAUKhPeWr

Comment: Try to eliminate parts of code until you determine what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular code is causing the issue (taking Skelly's approach)

```
 $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(".expect").offset().top
    }, 800,
```

I am unable find a reason why the above code causes the skip jump. But I do have solution which resolves this.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.step-tabs').on('click', function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 800);
    });
});


$('.btnNext').click(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});


$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

P.S - If anyone can explain the **reason** why his code wasn't working, I'll be able to die peacefully.

[**WORKING BOOTPLY**](http://www.bootply.com/IFCV8sEi4V)

Comment: Thank you. 

The code is actually working but is there a solution to show the next tab only when the scrollTop is completed?